# How to upgrade Python IDLE in raspberry pi desktop from 3.7 to 3.9

Tags: linux, python-3.7, python-idle, python-3.9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSdEh.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7hj0.png)I had install Python IDLE before and it was the 3.7.3 version. I had already tried both `sudo apt upgrade idle` and `sudo apt install idle` to see if it change to the 3.9 version or not. Is there anyway to change this or not? and if there nothing i can do, are there anyway to use the python 3.9 version on pi desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before .
First I changed to using python3 because raspberry uses python 2 by default you can check this website : visit https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/python-programming-tutorial-getting-started-with-the-raspberry-pi/configure-your-pi?fbclid=IwAR1BZqhI3oV55RKaOf0zzDZfQAdf2ZgOZ9XVSZDJHrbTor1ogzxVEf_ztsA

And then you can update the idle to python 3.9 I recommend to visit : https://raspberrytips.com/install-latest-python-raspberry-pi/ to finish your python upgrade

Comment: I had followed the instruction in your second link with other websites for several times and it still show idle 3.7.3 version, but i can run the code in Python 3.9 from the terminal as they said.

Comment: The path of Python 3.7 and Python 3.9 aren't the same . Check the usr/bin folder and usr/local

Comment: I checked both of them as show in the picture above and i uninstalled the idle and reinstalled again and this had shown up (Picture above).

Comment: it is working correctly right? , the version is what you are seeking for is 3.9

Comment: Yes, it is working smoothly. and i seek for IDLE 3.9.

Comment: By the way, my desktop computer is an i3 CPU with 32-bit processor. I don't know if this effect the installation process or not.

Comment: NO , it does not effect on the idle installation , but python you have now is 3.9 , the last digit 5 is a version from the version of python 3.9 and its the best one so far